# Wifi/Cellular Signal strength in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.forms, wifi

Need to show the Wifi/Cellular Signal in the form of:

```
Unknown,
None,
Weak,
Fair,
Strong
```

In Xamarin forms supporting iOS Platform...

Comment: Maybe you could ping some server and calibrate to the response time?

Answer (score 0):

There was a feature request for this in Xamarin.Essentials.

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/pull/647

After further investigation James Montemagno closed feature request and said:

> So, it looks like iOS is going to cause a big issue here. There is no API in there that returns the active wifi signal. The HotspotHelpers needs special requirements from Apple and you only get back information about your WiFi connection itself if you are managing it. The only option here is to probably put "Unknown" for iOS unless we try to call into a Unix property of some sort.

At the time being, as far as I know, nothing has changed. The public API that was available before was removed. So .. no iOS.