# How can we check signal strength either for mobile network or wifi in Xamarin forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

What i want to achive is restrict user not to reach server when user do not have a stable internet or consider user as offline.

I tried to like get a connection type but did not success. Its crashing when we are trying to get type`NetworkInfo`

- Android Code:

```
public static bool IsConnectedFast(Context context)
{
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService); 
     NetworkInfo info = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;

     TelephonyManager tm = TelephonyManager.FromContext(context);
     return (info != null && info.IsConnected && NetworkConnectivity.IsConnectionFast(info.Type, tm.NetworkType)); // Getting crash here when trying with mobile connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful info on the Internet. Have you tried them?

For Xamarin.Andriod,  you could use native API:

[How to get WIFI signal strength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/889551/how-to-get-wifi-signal-strength)

[How to get current WiFi signal strength in Xamarin.Forms running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75085517/how-to-get-current-wifi-signal-strength-in-xamarin-forms-running-on-android)

For Xamarin.iOS, many answers suggested that there is **no API** for iOS:

[Wifi/Cellular Signal strength in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588261/wifi-cellular-signal-strength-in-xamarin-forms)

[Xamarin form: How to check the signal strength on both android and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073955/xamarin-form-how-to-check-the-signal-strength-on-both-android-and-ios)

[Is it possible to get Wifi & Cellular signal strength on iOS?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97916)